# Spotify API retrieves my data for other users instead of theirs

Tags: python, python-requests, request, spotify, endpoint

I've been trying to write some code that requires a user's playlist using the Spotify API. It works fine when I run the code on my computer and with my login details, but when I get my teacher to run it on their computer with them logged in, it still fetches my playlists instead of theirs, even though they are logged in. I'm using OAuth 2.0 for their login, so it should have no problem with fetching their data as I have all the correct scopes enabled. Here is my code:

```
def getUsersPlaylists(self, offset): # Returns playlist that the user has created and liked
        headers = {
            "Authorization" : f"Bearer {self.access_token}"
        }
        endpoint = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/playlists?offset=' + str(offset) + '&limit=50'
        return requests.get(endpoint, headers=headers).json()
```

and here is the link to the documentation on the endpoint I'm using: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/get-a-list-of-current-users-playlists

I find it super strange that this is happening since, nowhere in my code do I store my own Spotify credentials anywhere in the code. This leads me to think that it is using my data because I am the one who created the API project.

If this is the case, is there a way I can get the playlist of the person actually logged in? Thanks to anyone who can help :)

Comment: Spotify supports public playlists. You sure you not see exactly these of yours?

Comment: Sorry, I'm having trouble understanding the second sentence of your reply. Could you please clarify what you mean? Thanks.

Comment: you wrote yiou see your playlists even if you did not log in. My question was if these playlists aren't your public playlists, so anyone can see them

Comment: Yes, most of my playlists are public. However, the documentation of the endpoint I am using in my function says that it should return the playlist of the user current logged in, right?

Comment: Did you add the name and email address of your teacher to the dashboard of your app? Your app is most likely still in [Development mode](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/concepts/quota-modes).

Comment: @Ximzend No I haven't. I had no idea I had to do this. I can't try it out to see if it works right now, but I assume this is the problem. Thank you!

Comment: @Ximzend I just tested it on my teacher's computer after adding him to my dashboard, but it still shows my playlist. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling the function?
It seems as you are sending the offset of your own playlists instead of checking the offset of the user.
I would check on what you are passing into the func and report back.
Edit:
Sorry, I rechecked and you are right, nothing seems off with your function. The problem must be from the loggin.

Comment: I'm just passing 0 into the function since I have less than 50 playlists. The offset is there in case the user has more than 50 playlists. In this case, you have to retrieve the first 50, then increment the offset by 50, then get the next 50 and so on. I don't see how this will change whos playlists I'm getting.